# Bootstrap 4 clicking nav menu toggler on mobile screen size pushes content down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav

When viewing this from xs or sm viewport/screen sizes, and then clicking on my navbar toggler, it's pushing all the content, INCLUDING the header that the navbar-toggler is in, down the page to make room for the dropdown menus.

This appears to be different from Bootstrap 3 (as well as Bootstrap 4 alpha 5).

Any thoughts on how to stop doing this?

Here's the site to test...
https://test.wrestlestat.com/rankings/dual

Here's the code:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler d-md-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            @*<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.ComparisonRoutes.GetDualComparisonSelectLink()">Dual Comparison</a></li>*@
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="comparisonDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Comparisons
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="comparisonDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.ComparisonRoutes.GetDualComparisonSelectLink()">Dual/Team</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.ComparisonRoutes.GetWrestlerComparisonSelectLink()">Wrestler</a>
                    @*<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>*@
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.ComparisonRoutes.GetDualComparisonSelectLink()">Perma</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="rankingsDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Rankings
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="rankingsDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.RankingRoutes.GetWrestlerRankingsAllLink()">Wrestler</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.RankingRoutes.GetDualRankingsLink()">Dual</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.RankingRoutes.GetTournamentRankingsLink()">Tournament</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="fantasyDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Comparisons
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="fantasyDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.PickEmRoutes.GetFantasyThisWeekLink()">Pick'Em</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.TourneyPoolRoutes.GetTourneyPoolHubLink()">Tourney Pool</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@WrestleStat_v3.Core.Constants.Route.TourneyProjectionRoutes.GetTourneyProjectionLink()">Tourney Projection</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why it happens?**
The class `sticky-top` gives your navbar a `position: sticky;` which acts as a block element when you haven't scrolled yet. So when your navbar gets expanded it pushes all other block elements down.

**Fix1 - pushes normal content down**
Put this div: `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style>...</div>` at the end of your `<nav>...</nav>`, or above your `input` if you want the searchfield to be under the collapsed navbar.

**Fix2 - doesn't push anything down**
First do **Fix1**, then in your CSS add `.sticky-top { position: fixed !important; }`, *Only do this if your not using `sticky-top` anywere else!*,  because when you don't scroll it acts like a block element so pushes its other content down.  Also add some margin to your first `container-fluid` so its under the header again (cause the now `fixed` element doesn't take up space anymore) for example add classes `pt-5` and `mt-5` to them.

Comment: That stops the header/menu/navbar from moving down when toggling, but the page content still get's pushed down....maybe I can live with that

Comment: @ganders I edited my answer, take a look if you like this one more. But bootstrap intended to do it this way, cause now you can still see other content while expanding the navbar. (I kinda like this)

Comment: Thanks for option 2. That doesn't work for me either since I use a sticky left-side navbar on md(up). I believe I'm just going to use option 1, especially since that's the new bootstrap behavior. Thanks!

Comment: @ganders np, please accept this as answer if this helped you enough :)

Comment: @ganders if you still rather want option 2 you can allways add another class (like `custom-fixed`) and add css like `.custom-fixed { position: fixed !important; }` or something like that.